# How assign a list in a new column of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe on R with 4 columns that correspond to the results of my experiment. I would like to insert the ID column to display the participants' ID of each row. ID changes every 110 trials, that is the first 110 rows could display "ID of participant 1". The next 110 rows (that is from row 111 to 220) could display "ID of participant 2" etc. I have a list in R of the participants' ID. Do you know how can I assign a list of ID participants in a new column?

Thanks

PM

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you could use `rep()`

```
ids = c()
for(i in id_list){
    ids=c(ids, rep(i, 110)
}

df$ID = ids
```

plus next time when you post a question, it would help others to post example of your data